# Deep Learning algorithm to calculate output of two parameters based on training data

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, parameters

I have to optimize my Parameters in order to get the highest Energy cusumption. I think no Need to explain the physical phenomenon I'm studying but the important informations are: Let's say I have two variables which are the frequency F and the Magnitude A. The Energy consumption Y is not calculated through an equation but with a complex Simulation in Ansys. From Ansys I can have the Energy Y for every Frequency and Magnitude combination I choose. is there a Deep learning technique which allows to use some variables and their Output Energy as Training data to create a Networks which would calculate the Output Energy for every other Parameter combination.
Ideas are welcome …

Comment: Exact duplicate of closed question: [Which algorithm should I use for THIS Maximization problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101475/which-algorithm-should-i-use-for-this-maximization-problem)

Comment: That Question was somehow closed and is not allowing any answer. It is actually deletet by now. thx. :)